# Scanf / Printf unexpected behavior

Tags: c, arrays

Iam supposed to create a two dimensional dynamic char array.

The array itself works, if i fill it with B[i][j] = input++ (input is declared as char input = 'a').

output:

a b

c d

As soon, as i want to read in my own inputs i start getting problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef char *Vector;
typedef Vector *Matrix;

int main(){
  int r, c, i, j;
  printf("Matrix dimension?\n");
  scanf("%d %d", &r, &c );
  Matrix B;
  B = (Matrix) malloc(r*sizeof(Vector));
  for(i = 0; i < r; i++){
    B[i] = (Vector) malloc(c*sizeof(char));
  }
  printf("input\n");           
  for(i = 0; i < r; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < c; j++){
  //B[i][j] = inhalt++;
      scanf("%c\n", &B[i][j] );
    }
  }
  for(i = 0; i < r; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < c; j++){
      printf("%c", B[i][j] );
    }
   printf("\n");
  }
  for(i = 0; i < (r-1); i++){
    free(B[i]);
  }
  free(B);
  return 0;
}
```

Input: 2 2 / a b c d

Output:

a

b c

I dont know why it doesnt read or print my first input.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: This seems like a very good idea to learn how to use a *debugger*. With a debugger you can step through your code statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values. Hopefully it should help you understand what's going on.

Comment: As a matter of style, do not hide pointer nature behind typedefs.  Doing so usually makes your code harder to read and understand.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, but sadly its required for the task im doing.

Comment: Tip: rather than `B = (Matrix) malloc(r*sizeof(Vector));`, consider the form `B = malloc(sizeof *B * r);`.  The cast is not needed and sizing by the referenced type  is easier to code right, review and maintain.

Comment: if you type "2 2 <return>" than the next scanf "%c" will read a newline character in B[0][0].  Your output would be
<newline> a <newline> b c. For very simple tasks, you could call getchar() after each scanf to solve the problem of a dangling newline. In real life you would use getline() or similar and a parser to read user input.

Comment: Not the source of your problem, but you should `free` the `B[r-1]` too; your freeing loop should be like that: `for(i = 0; i < r; i++) { free(B[i]); }`